# Request for member 'pin' in something is not a structure or union. MGTwitterEngine

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I'm wondering why I keep getting this error. I just added Twitter+Oauth folder from Ben Gottlieb code : https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone and when I tried to build it giving me that error.

SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m

```
- (void) setPin: (NSString *) pin {
    [_pin autorelease];
    _pin = [pin retain];

    _accessToken.pin = pin;
    _requestToken.pin = pin;
}
```

FYI, I've already added the xml library and set the Header Search Path. I also have check that 'pin'  declared in OAToken class where _accessToken is the pointer of that class.

Can anyone explain to me what I've done wrong here..

Comment: How did you get this problem solved? I too am struck with these errors.